# CMakeでFindHoge.cmakeの格納場所をハードコーディングしないで指定するには

Tags: build, cmake

CMakeで環境非依存なビルドファイルを作ろうとしています。
find_package()でLLVMやffiのConfig.cmakeフィアルを利用しようとしたところ、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいました。set()を利用してパスを指定するとエラーは消えますが、CMakeLists.txtに環境依存なパスがハードコードしており、当初の目的を達成できません。
ハードコードなしにConfig.cmakeファイルの格納場所を指定する方法を教えていただきたいです。

set(LLVM_DIR ...)しない場合のエラー

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
  the following names:

    LLVMConfig.cmake
    llvm-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LLVM"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(sample)
# 明示的にLLVM_DIRを指定するとエラーが消えるが環境依存になってしまう
set(LLVM_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.1/share/llvm/cmake)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

OS X Yosemite環境, HomeBrewでインストールしたllvmを指定した場合のCMakeLists.txtです。
MintLinuxでは/usr/share/llvm-3.5/cmake/に格納されているため、書き換えが必要でした。バージョンの変化も考えると他の方法があると思いました。

---

5/15 19:00頃追記

cmake実行時に以下のように指定することで外出しが可能でした。

```
cmake -D LLVM_DIR=/path/to/LLVMConfig.cmake
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決されたようですが、clang に PATH を通して

```
CC=clang cmake .
```

という方法もあるようです。